# Event is not fired at all

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, events

I've got a ComboBox, with a number of ComboBoxItems. I would like to fire an event when the user hovers over a ComboBoxItem with the mouse. This is the code I've tried so far, however the event is not firing - i.e. when I place a break point, the event is not entered.

```
private void cmbValue_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
            cmb.Items.Clear();

            //Iterates through all virtual tables
            foreach (TableContainer table in listOpenUnjoinedTables)
            {
                ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
                item.MouseEnter += item_MouseEnter;

                if (table.IsVirtual == false)
                {
                    item.Content = "[" + table.TableDescription + "]";
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Content = "[" + table.View.Name + "]";
                }

                item.Tag = table;
                cmb.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

 private void item_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxItem item = sender as ComboBoxItem;

            //Do task
        }
```

Comment: How do you assign the event handler to the `ComboBox`?

Comment: @DHN It's being assigned to the ComboBoxItem - `item.MouseEnter += item_MouseEnter;`

Comment: He does `item.MouseEnter += item_MouseEnter;`

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. I missed that part. My bad...

Comment: Well perhaps you have to override the handler of the `MouseEnter` event of the `ComboBox`. It's probably consuming the event (`e.Handled = true`), so that the `ComboBoxItem` doesn't receive it.

Comment: Or you may use the PreviewMouseMove event (if you don't need to know when mouse will leave...)

Comment: @Adriano - I actually do need to know when the mouse will leave too. I have this problem in both MouseEnter and Mouseleave

Comment: What WPF Inspector says about that event? WHO handles it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the GotFocus event. This will fire even if the user uses the keyboard to select an item. I believe that is what you indeed want here :)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var comboBoxItem1 = new ComboBoxItem();
        var comboBoxItem2 = new ComboBoxItem();

        comboBoxItem1.Content = new Button() { Content = "button1" };
        comboBoxItem1.GotFocus += (sender, args) => lbl1.Content = "1111";
        comboBoxItem2.Content = "222222";
        comboBoxItem2.GotFocus += (sender, args) => lbl1.Content = "2222";

        comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBoxItem1);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBoxItem2);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well if you hover over a `Control`, it won't get the focus. So I don't see, how this should work. Pls correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: May be I don't understand the problem here. If so please excuse me. It is working for me though.

Comment: Could you ulpoad a sample project maybe? As i tried the code but it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally delete the event on designer.cs?

Comment: I don't think it's that - I created a new project and the problem is there too.